# React native FTP fault within module

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ftp, expo

I was trying to run the ftp example from  the [react-native-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ftp) module.

What I did was I created a new project using expo and then installed the ftp module:

```
npm install react-native-ftp --save
```

Than I changed app.js into the following:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import FTP from 'react-native-ftp';

const loginPressHandler = () => {
   console.log("test")
   FTP.setup("192.168.1.1",21) //Setup host
   FTP.login("username","password").then(
      (result)=>{
        FTP.list(".").then(
            (result)=>{
               console.log(result);
             }
         );
       },
       (error)=>{
        alert(error);
       }
   )
 };

 export default function App() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Button title="Log in" onPress={loginPressHandler}/>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     backgroundColor: '#fff',
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center',
   },
});
```

But when I run this using expo start I get the following error when I press the button:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeFtp.default.setup')
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError 
- node_modules\expo-error-recovery\build\ErrorRecovery.fx.js:9:32 in 
 ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:293:29 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:154:27 in invoke
- node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:164:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

I get the same when I fill in a valid username, password and host for an ftp server. The error seems to be within the ftp module so I have actually no idea how to debug this.

Comment: I don't think you could use this library with `expo`. The library requires you to link with the android. Expo doesn't allow linking.

Comment: oh okay thanks for that!